# SAPUI5 OData v4 model authentication with cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, odata, sapui5

i'm currently trying to consume an OData v4 service with the OData v4 model of OpenUI5. The service requires an authentication by sending a session id as a cookie.

My problem is now that the model does not include the cookie in the generated request header so that i'm getting *not authorised* as a response.
The session id is set in the *document.cookie* with the correct name and value but i can see in the developer tools of my browser that the cookie is not part of the request header.

I hope you can help me with this problem. Many thanks in advance!